# ObservableCollection made of strings Not updating

Tags: xamarin, data-binding

Ok, so, I'm trying to link an ObservableCollection from my Android project to my Cross-Platform Project::

I've got this so far...this is in my Cross-platform app

```
        ObservableCollection<String> NewRef = DependencyService.Get<ISlateBluetoothItems>().test().testThing;
        NewRef.CollectionChanged += TestThing_CollectionChanged;
        listView.ItemsSource = NewRef;


    private void TestThing_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        listView.ItemsSource = DependencyService.Get<ISlateBluetoothItems>().test().testThing;
        Console.WriteLine("working");

    }
```

The line "working" is never printed even if I make changes to the ObservableCollection on the android portion of my app...

Here's the interface I'm using for the DependencyService:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

  namespace ThoughtCastRewrite.BluetoothX
{
    public interface ISlateBluetoothItems 
    {

        BluetoothItems test();


    }
}
```

Here's the class I use to expose the list:

```
namespace ThoughtCastRewrite.BluetoothX
{
    public class BluetoothItems 
    {
        public ObservableCollection<String> testThing;




        public BluetoothItems()
        {
            testThing = new ObservableCollection<String>();

            testThing.Add("wtf?");


        }

        public void AddThis()
        {
            testThing.Add("ok");

        }

    }
}
```

This is in the Android portion of my app, it implements the  ISlateBluetoothItems interface
 BluetoothItems bluetoothItems = new BluetoothItems();

then I call

```
bluetoothItems.AddThis();
```

but "ok" is not added to my list! I don't get the CollectionChanged event firing off! What's the deal guys? What's the deal?

Answer (score 0):

You should assign your ObservableCollection as a source of your listview only once, not after each change. Changes to the collection will be automaticcly propagated to the listview.